# OnActivityResult when having GUI parts outside Fragment

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I have a two pane fragment design with the detail fragment dealing with the item clicked on the leftmost, listfragment.

Since I have many different list items, they have different GUI's each one of them, I want to put the handling of the GUI parts in different separate classes.
I'm using reflections to get the code slimmed inside the ItemDetailFragment:(code below is stripped down)

```
*//get class gui_handler for the object and get its constructor:*
Constructor<?> ctor = mListItem.getmGuiHandler().getConstructor(View.class);

*//create an object of the gui_handler class, pass the rootView as arg:*
gui_handler_base handlerObject = (gui_handler_base) ctor.newInstance(root);

*//run setup-method containing findViewById() and more GUI related stuff:*
handlerObject.setupGUI(mListItem, getActivity());
```

In setupGUI:

```
public void setupGUI(MyListItem item, final Activity activity) {
  buttonRun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
                final String FILENAME = "XXX";
                Intent I = new Intent(activity,KTActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putSerializable("FileName",FILENAME);
                I.putExtras(b);
                activity.startActivityForResult(I,1);
                return;
            }
        });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
// I WANT TO END UP HERE WHEN THE ACTIVITY RETURNS;
}
```

I have one onActivityResult method in the gui_handler_base class and one in the ItemDetailFragment, but none of them are called.
How can I do this??

Comment: I have know idea what you're asking here and as far as I can tell your design doesn't fit standard Android design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite ambiguous. Why are you using onActivityResult? activity.startActivityForResult(I,1); why?  WHy not just implement the onclicklistener class in your fragment class and be done with it? It seems like in trying to reduce code you created more headaches for yourself. Also take out numbers in your code and use constants.  You have to call the intent and use the intent in the same fragment. Further more why are you extracting out the GUI functionality from the fragments? You shouldn't be. even if you are creating custom functionality, you would still deal with a fragment's functionality in the fragment.

```
  //if you want to try this… normally when receiving a camera intent this is what you can do. 
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case yourResultCode:
        doSomethingWithYourResult;
        break;
      ]
```

Comment: I thought it was obvious that I want to end up in onActivityResult for dealing with the result later on.
I cleared the method before posting because it is not the method itself that is the core of my question.

I distribute GUI parts in seperate classes to keep the fragment class short, I have tons of code doing different things so I think it's good to design my app this way.

The problem is not dealing with the result itself (resultCode...) it's that OnActivityResult is not being called because it is outside the fragment class.

Comment: Again why are you putting your GUI code outside the fragment.  That is not good code design. You might have different utility classes that might process information, but for GUi, most of that should be happening in the controller classes. Fragments should be doing their own work.  That is the whole point of the activities and frags; they are controllers by nature.  Think of MVC.  In terms of the result.   It was obvious what you are trying to do, but what is not clear is why? In other words what are you doing with the result? That is not clear.  What is the justification?

Comment: I want to encapsulate different GUI behaviours Into different seperate classes. I Will have to deal with alot of control code and I dont wanna end up with a fragment class having >10000 lines of code. Thats why.

Comment: Well if you will have >10000 lines of code you are doing way too much in one fragment.  Why don't you process your UI in the frag and all none-ui functionality in util classes? It will reduce your code.